When does isomorphism on singular cohomology imply isomorphism on Picard and Brauer groups?
Assume  that  $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of complex varieties, and the homomorphisms $H^i_\text{sing}(f)$ are bijective for $0\le i\le 3$ (though possibly $3$ is too much here:)). Under which assumptions on $X$ and $Y$ one can deduce that $\operatorname{Pic}(f)$ and $\operatorname{Br}(f)$ are bijective?
Probably, a well-known idea here is to apply the exponential sequence. Consequently, I would like to know whether the corresponding $H^i(-,\mathcal{O})(f)$ are bijective. Respectively, which assumptions are needed to deduce that $f$ induces isomorphisms on cohomology with coefficients in the structure sheaves? This is clearly true when $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective; yet can one weaken these assumptions?
Lastly, what can one do about the characteristic $p>0$ case? I actually consider étale cohomology (with any prime to $p$ torsion coefficients) instead of singular cohomology. Can one say anything better than that the corresponding kernels and cokernels are uniquely prime-to-$p$-divisible?

In a smooth projective case in characteristic $p$ an isomorphism of étale cohomology gives an isomorphism of rational crystalline cohomology via the Weil conjectures. So maybe that gets you something more.

This may help; thank you! Yet for smooth projectives only, yes?

Well one can do something for complements of hyperplane arrangements also but that's an even more specific case.

Obviously, if the first Chern classes for $X$ and $Y$ are surjective, then the Brauer groups are isomorphic (even $H^{3}_\text{sing}(X)_\text{tors} \cong H^{3}_\text{sing}(Y)_\text{tors}$ is sufficient).
